# AGOL webhook to Integromat/Google Sheets

Tags: arcgis-online, integration, http, post, google-sheets

I have a feature layer in AGOL.

Whenever edits are made to features in the layer, I want to POST those edits/attributes to an external system for testing purposes.

- In this case, the external system is [Integromat](http://Integromat.com) (that points to a Google Sheet).

How can I set up an AGOL webhook and point it toward Integromat/Google Sheets?

---

Related:

[Create a hosted feature service webhook](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/sharing-collaboration/how-to-create-a-hosted-feature-service-webhook/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full Integromat solution:

---

[image]

---

This JSON can be imported into Integromat to create the scenario (file download): https://drive.google.com/file/d/14AXG9-zK2eGxBxHiWK9lFqoyHfswbdQ8/view?usp=sharing

[image]

---

Note:

A couple of the HTTP request steps would work sometimes, and fail other times.

It seemed to be necessary to give those steps adequate time to process before I sent a subsequent request. I used sleep modules in Integromat to add a slight delay (1-second).

Answer (score 2):

This solution gets us **part of the way there:**

When features are edited in the feature layer, an AGOL webhook sends a POST request to [Integromat](http://Integromat.com)/Google sheets.

[image]

However, the result is just information *about* the edit—it does not contain any of the attributes from the edited feature.

---

---

Here are the steps:

**AGOL:**

1. `AGOL` --> `Content`: Click your feature layer and then go to the  `Settings` tab.
2. In the `Feature Layer (hosted)` --> `Editing` section, ensure that `Keep track of created and updated features.` is checked.
3. Click `Save`.
4. Go back to the `Overview` tab (in Content) and click the `Feature Service` link (in `Details` -->
   `Source: Feature Service`).
5. In the URL of that FeatureServer page, type `/admin` between `/rest/services/` like so: `/rest/admin/services/`. Hit Enter.
6. Click the `webhooks` link at the bottom of the page.
7. Click the `Create` hyperlink.
8. You should be able to see the webhook page:

[image]

---

---

**Integromat:**

We'll use [Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/) and Google Sheets as an external system to POST to:

9. Create an Integromat account.
10. Click `Scenarios` in the left pane.
11. Click `Create a new scenario` in the top right corner.
12. Search for "webhooks".
13. Select the `webhooks` module and then click `Continue` in the top right corner.
14. Click webhooks:

[image]

15. Click `Custom webhook`.
16. Click `Add` and give your webhook a name.
17. Click Save.
18. A URL is generated. Click `Copy address to clipboard`:

[image]

---

---

**AGOL:**

19. Paste in the URL to the AGOL webhook:

[image]

20. Click `Create`.
21. The following webhook is created:

[image]

22. Go to a map in Web Map Viewer (or whatever you use to edit features) and make an edit to a feature.

---

---

**Integromat:**

23. We can see that the AGOL webhook successfully sent the request to Integromat:

[image]

24. Exit out of the webhooks dialog.
25. We'll configure the webhook so that it captures the data in a Google Sheet:

[image]

26. Click `Add a row`.
27. Create a connection to your Gmail account.
28. Select the Google Drive spreadsheet that you want the data to go into.

[image]

28. Select `payload` in the Google Sheet field that you want the webhook data to go into.
29. Click `OK` and click the Save button in the bottom toolbar:

[image]

30. Turn it `ON` and click `Activate`.

[image]

---

---

**Create a new feature and test:**

31. In AGOL, create a new feature.
32. The record should show up in the Google sheet (in 30 seconds).

[image]